# Get union of all allowed types inside an interface [Typescript]

Tags: typescript

Is there a way in Typescript to get a union of all the *types* defined inside an interface?

So for example if I have an interface:

```
interface Events {
    connect: () => void;
    message: (data: object) => void;
}
```

I can get a union of its keys by using `keyof Events` which will yield `"connect" | "message"`. Is there some equivalent way of getting a union of allowed types, which would yield `(() => void) | ((data: object) => void)`?

Comment: You use an [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) type along with `keyof`, like `Events[keyof Events]`.  See the answer to the linked question for more information